# Bigquery - Return array of structs with specific fields of the struct

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have an array of structs in bigquery.
I would like to return an array of structs, but the struct of the array with less fields that the original struct.

Example:

[image]

I would like to have the same results but without Skills.Id.

I tried to do something like this but

```
  SELECT  [(select struct(dd.Level as Level, dd.TypeId as typeid)
                  from unnest(dd.Skills) as dd  )]  as skills    
   FROM tablee dd
```

But get an exception:

`Scalar subquery produced more than one element`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [ARRAY](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays#creating_arrays_from_subqueries) instead of `[]`:

```
SELECT ARRAY(select struct(dd.Level as Level, dd.TypeId as typeid) 
             from unnest(tablee.Skills) as dd) as skills    
FROM tablee
```